# C# WPF/MVVM 異なるxamlにある要素へBindingする方法は？

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

C# WPF/MVVM にて、次のように異なるxamlにある要素へBindingする方法がわかりません。
この場合、Menu.xamlにあるIsCheckedとPane.xamlにあるIsEnabledを紐付けするにはどうしたらいいですか？

・Menu.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sample.Menu" ...>
  <Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="メニュー1">
      <MenuItem Header="項目1" 
        IsCheckable="True"
        IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=Pane1}" />
    </MenuItem>
  </Menu>
</UserControl>
```

・Pane.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sample.Pane" ...>
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="Pane1" IsEnabled="False">...</StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

・MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Sample.MainWindow" ...>
  <Grid>
    <local:Menu />
    <local:Pane Grid.Row="1" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

それぞれの`UserControl`内部のプロパティを`UserControl`のプロパティにバインドすればよいです。

たとえば`Pane.IsEnabled`にバインドするためには以下のようになります。

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel
            IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=IsEnabled}">
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

バインド対象のプロパティは独自に定義してもよいです。

```
// Menu.xaml.cs
public bool IsEnabled2
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsEnabled2Property); }
    set { SetValue(IsEnabled2Property, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEnabled2Property =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsEnabled2", typeof(bool), typeof(Menu), new PropertyMetadata(true));
```

なお上記の定義はエディター上で`propdp`と入力し、タブキーを二回押すと生成することが出来ます。

最後に`MainWindow`内で通常の`ElementName`を使用した`{Binding}`で相互にバインドを行います。

```
<local:Menu
    x:Name="menu" />
<local:Pane
    IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=menu, Path=IsEnabled2}" />
```